# Get data from other user_id with facebook graph API v3.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, userid

I would like to know if it is possible to get basic data (name, posts...) of user in Facebook that has public profile (obviously).

I tried with GRAPH API this call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/USER_ID?fields=id,name&access_token=access_token
```

When I use my profile USER_ID, it returns my id and my name, but when I put another user ID, it returns this error:

```
Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'USER_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api
```

But I reed in documentation that the variable `user_id` can use in this API call, so I think that this is posible (maybe no).

I reed in other posts, that in the past you can access by username, but now no. Maybe, you only can access to your profile data?

Thanks and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not access just anyone’s profile data via API, even if it is shown publicly on the website or the official apps.

The user would need to explicitly login to your app and grant it permission to access their data. Those permissions can not be granted on behalf of someone else - every single user you would want any info about, would have to do this personally.

Comment: And if I have a "page" in facebook, I can get information about it? Thanks

Comment: For pages you have admin access to, you can use a page access token to get info about them. For just general public pages, you need to get your app reviewed for the feature “Page Public Content Access” first, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS